# C# WebBrowser HTML Get ByClass not working

Tags: c#, html

Everyone Hello I'm Türk (Türkiye)

```
<div class="asdq">TestMessageBox</div>
```

I've tried, working

```
<div class="asdq qwet">TestMessageBox</div>
```

these codes do not work

Peki nasıl çözebilirim?

C# GetByClass C# I put the codes (class="asdq qwet" not working.):

```
HtmlElementCollection theElementCollection = default(HtmlElementCollection);
        theElementCollection = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");
        foreach (HtmlElement curElement in theElementCollection)
        {
            if (curElement.GetAttribute("className").ToString() == "asdq qwet")
            {
                MessageBox.Show(curElement.GetAttribute("InnerText"));
            }
        }
```

Comment: it should be curElement.GetAttribute("class") instead of curElement.GetAttribute("className") ?  Did you try this ?

Answer (score 0):

It is working with winform application in .net 4.6.1.

I have tested with following html file in webbrowser1 instance in yo

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="asdq qwet">TestMessageBox with qwet</div> 
<div class="asdq">TestMessageBox</div>
</body
</html>
```

there must be some type error in your html otherwise it is working correctly